# Cannot connect to Yahoo Webhosting using lftp and FTPS from Ubuntu

Tags: ftps, lftp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, and I use Yahoo Webhosting, and I also have my own domain "example.com". I used to use FTP to transfer files to/from my webhosting account to update my website. But now Yahoo has just ended support for FTP, and now they require users to use only FTPS. I am happy about this change, because I know that FTP is insecure, and the move to FTPS is necessary. So I found lftp (http://lftp.yar.ru/), which seems to be a FTPS client that I could use to transfer files to/from Yahoo Webhosting. I was able to install it with "sudo apt-get install lftp", but when I try to connect to Yahoo Webhosting, it doesn't work.

Here's my system information:

user@hostname:~/Desktop >> more /etc/issue.net 
Ubuntu 12.10

user@hostname:~/Desktop >> uname -a
Linux mojave 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:05:29 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

user@hostname:~/Desktop >> lftp -v
LFTP | Version 4.3.8 | Copyright (c) 1996-2012 Alexander V. Lukyanov

LFTP is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with LFTP.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

Send bug reports and questions to the mailing list .

Libraries used: Readline 6.2, GnuTLS 2.12.14, zlib 1.2.7

Here's how I used to do it:
user@hostname:~/Desktop >> ftp username@ftp.example.com

Now, I try the command below, but it doesn't work:
user@hostname:~/Desktop >> lftp username@ftp.example.com
Password: 
lftp username@ftp.example.com:~> ls
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/username/keyring-EvxB3g/pkcs11: No such file or directory
ls: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted
lftp username@ftp.example.com:~> quit

What am I doing wrong? How do I get lftp to create an FTPS session to Yahoo Webhosting?

Thanks in advance for any help!! I really appreciate it!!

Steve McMahon

Answer (score 7):

It took me a while to figure this out but I was able to get it working using lftp like so:

```
lftp
set ssl:verify-certificate false
set ftp:ssl-force true
connect ftp.example.com
login username@somewhere.com
Password:
```

Answer (score 0):

The method above worked for me connecting from Ubuntu 14 to Yahoo webhosting using ftps. To reduce typing, the lftp commands shown above where placed into a text file and -f was used to read the text file.  Below are the two files, a shell script to run lftp and the lftp script.

```
The shell script contains:
  #! /bin/bash
  # script name: ylist.sh
  echo "Get Directory List from Yahoo via FTPS"
  lftp -f ylist-script.txt

The ylist-script.txt file contains:
  set ssl:verify-certificate false
  set ftp:ssl-force true
  connect ftp.example.com
  login username@example.com
  ls
```

These retrieve a directory list from the root of the yahoo webhosting account. lftp exits and when script completes.